# Is there a way to compile program with RAD Studio XE7 to work in windows 98?

Tags: delphi, windows-98

*I uninstall delphi7 For a while and i install RAD Studio XE7*

Is there a way to compile program with RAD Studio to work in windows 98 **without reinstall delphi 7**?

Comment: I've tried it before and work

Comment: If you need to support *any* operating system for which mainstream support ended >15 years ago, chances are current tools will no longer support it. Is there a particular reason you don't want to reinstall Delphi 7?

Comment: @Asad: you could be lucky and it runs, but you can just as well be unlucky and it doesn't. It very much depends on which APIs are being used. Trivial programs probably run.

Comment: You know what to do. Install Delphi 7.

Comment: Hard drive space is low and I don't need Delphi 7 after that

Comment: I suppose the question is, do you want to target Windows 98 or not. If you do, then you need a version of Delphi that can meet your needs. Delphi 7 does, XE7 does not. The choice is yours. Install Delphi 7 and be able to target Windows 98, or don't install Delphi 7 and not be able to target Windows 98.

Comment: To be fair, you *could* compile a GUI application in XE7 that would run on Win98, but you would have to rewrite or re-implement most of the RTL and VCL.

Comment: if your hard drive space is so low that an installation of Delphi 7 is too much for it, than I think you have other troubles soon anyway... It really does not takes much space, about 350 MB i believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot target Windows 9x using modern Delphi. There are plenty of reasons for this but the big one is Unicode. Since Delphi 2009 the Delphi libraries target the Unicode variant of the Win32 API. Windows 9x does not support Unicode.

If you wish to continue targeting Windows 9x, do so the way you always have done. Use Delphi 7.

Comment: thank you @david  ,So there is no other way except to install delphi7

Comment: Well, there are other versions that could be used, like Delphi 6 for instance. And I'm sure you could do it with certain versions of fpc and Lazarus. But you have Delphi 7, you know it does what you need. I don't see any reason to look elsewhere.

Comment: If I do not use Windows commands in my project, will this change anything?, does the compiler changed between RAD and Delphi 7 ,Even if the project is a Console.

Comment: The Delphi runtime calls the Win32 API. Your process won't even startup. It will have dependencies on Unicode APIs that don't exist. It won't even make it past the loader. Plus you'll have to convert all your code from Delphi 7 to XE7 which is no mean task. Install Delphi 7. What on earth is stopping you?

Comment: Also, you've got to ask yourself what your program could achieve if it never called the Win32 API. It could not do any IO. It couldn't present any UI. The fact that your **code** does not call a Win32 API function directly in no way means that your **program** does not.

Comment: For completeness, the Microsoft Layer for Unicode did add some incomplete Unicode support to Win9x, but this required applications to be specifically written to target MSLU. Given that Win9x was long dead by the time Delphi switched to Unicode, there was no point in Delphi targeting MSLU.

Comment: @AsadAlamdar If your project is a console application than it might work but there is no guarante for that. Now if you check the Delphi XE7 documentation you Will see that Delphi XE7 officialy no longer support Windows XP any more and WinXP is much younger OS than Win98

Comment: @SilverWarior Nope, won't work for a console app either

Comment: No one stopping me , but I wanted to understand why (motivated by knowledge only), thank you all for that information